# Delete query with 4 where-like statements very slow

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a delete query which goes on around 300k datarows:

```
DELETE FROM austan_f 
WHERE (Bez LIKE '%XX' OR 
       Bez LIKE '%YY' OR 
       Bez LIKE '%ZZ' OR 
       Bez LIKE 'FHK%' OR 
       length(Bez) != 8)
```

It needs around 30 minutes - the "why" is not the problem: 4x like is bad as hell - the problem is, I don't know how to do it better.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does it matter -- it is probably a one-time operation?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE austan_f;`.  How big is the table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Optimizing Searches with LIKE or FULLTEXT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091448/mysql-optimizing-searches-with-like-or-fulltext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression (this will take care of the length check as well):

```
DELETE FROM austan_f WHERE Bez REGEXP '(^FHK)|(XX|YY|ZZ)$|^(.{0,7}|.{9,})$';
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Do you think regrexp will be faster?